# Is there a way to manage authentication for web services with Flask?

Tags: python, web-services, authentication, flask

I am trying to use flask in order to provide http based web-services to an android application. I have found that flask-login is the easiest way to manage authentication but it seems to be oriented to template based web application.

Is there another solution for web-service based authentication?

Comment: What do you mean by template based web application? What problem do you have with using flask-login?

Comment: I mean for standard web pages and not web services, with REST web service you can't have sessions and so the flask-login module will not be able to do the job.

Comment: Unless you are using shared secrets of some kind REST services still need to be able to handle session and / or authentication keys (otherwise you can't authenticate and *then* perform a call to the necessary endpoint).  Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flask-Login` good solution. You can add next decorator for views:

```
def login_required():
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.is_authenticated():
                abort(401)
                # return jsonify(status='logged_off')
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper
```

So if user don't authorized any view with `login_required` decorator return `401 Unauthorized` response (or valid response with custom message if you want).